# How to fix executenonquery() for looping for-next

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i want insert data from datagridview to sqlserver, what command for stop looping for-next at my coding? im getting error after running my application, but data from datagridview already moved to sqlserver.

i try to move command.ExecuteNonQuery() after next and still getting error.

```
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO temp_plu (itemid, judul, soh, location,kodevendor,namavendor) VALUES (@itemid,@judul,@soh,@location,@kodevendor,@namavendor)"

    command.Parameters.Add("@itemid", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@judul", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@soh", SqlDbType.Int)
    command.Parameters.Add("@location", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@kodevendor", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@namavendor", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    connection.Open()
        command.Connection = connection

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

            command.Parameters(0).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            command.Parameters(1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            command.Parameters(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            command.Parameters(3).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            command.Parameters(4).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
            command.Parameters(5).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
```

Comment: Can you tell us what error you are getting, please?

Comment: You're going about this in completely the wrong way.  No loop needed.  Just bind a `DataTable` to your grid and then call `Update` on a data adapter to save the whole lot in a single batch.

Comment: @jayV The parameterized query '(@itemid nvarchar(4000),@judul nvarchar(4000),@soh int,@location' expects the parameter '@itemid', which was not supplied.@jayv thats error but data already moved to sqlserver

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you give me some example? i moved data sqlserver A to datagridview and than i moved again to sqlserver B..

Comment: [This example](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&p=3112830&viewfull=1#post3112830) uses a data adapter and a `DataTable`. It adds a row to the `DataTable` in code but you can easily bind your `DataTable` to the grid. If you don't know how, look it up.

Comment: Try `DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2` If the user can add rows, the grid has an extra blank row.